# PBS/Torque cannot finalize the result of computation

Tags: ssh, pbs, torque

I have installed Torque on Ubuntu machine (it's the server and the only node). And it seems like jobs are working fine except for the finalization part.

When the job ends, I get something like

```
PBS Job Id: 17.ubuntu-server
Job Name:   dm.job
Exec host:  ubuntu-server/0
An error has occurred processing your job, see below.
Post job file processing error; job 17.ubuntu-server on host ubuntu-server/0

Unable to copy file /var/spool/torque/spool/17.ubuntu-server.OU to user@ubuntu-server:/home/user/test/dm.job.o17
*** error from copy
Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
*** end error output
Output retained on that host in: /var/spool/torque/undelivered/17.ubuntu-server.OU

Unable to copy file /var/spool/torque/spool/17.ubuntu-server.ER to user@ubuntu-server:/home/user/test/dm.job.e17
*** error from copy
Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
*** end error output
Output retained on that host in: /var/spool/torque/undelivered/17.ubuntu-server.ER
```

As I understand, the problem is the authentication with ssh keys. It tries to scp some files to the job folder, but ssh permissions are wrong. I put my own `id_rsa.pub` into `authorized_keys` (and root's also), but still no luck.

So a couple of question related:

1. Under which user jobs are run? I guess, if I write `qsub dm.job`, it runs under my user. So if I am able to ssh from `user@ubuntu-server` to `user@ubuntu-server` (which I am), there shouldn't be problem with job output scp'ing (which still is). If it's the root user that executes job, how one need to properly setup ssh credentials and keys?
2. How to fix this permission error?

And slightly offtopic, but relatable. Why several script names aren't recognizable? For example, I can write

```
> julia -v
julia version 0.6.0
```

both under root and myself. But when I run in inside the job, it logs

```
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/18.ubuntu-server.SC: line 5: julia: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The job isn't running from your submit node; it gets assigned to a compute node for execution, so the file is being scp'ed from that compute node to the node where you submitted. You can check where the job ran by running `qstat -f | grep exec_host`. There should be something at the front that looks something like hostname\index and might have some things after that. The first hostname is where the job is executing (unless you are on a Cray, in which case it's the second hostname).